# MongoDB Promise Library

Tags: javascript, mongodb, cmd, promise, es6-promise

Giving Mongo the instruction to use the ES6 promiselibrary, 
using this code:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

but I still get the following error:

```
(node:17264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: done is not defined
(node:17264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix this?

Comment: I'd start by looking for where you are using `done` - which is undefined - what do you think `done` is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the possibility of rejection of the promise.  This reference might help
http://thecodebarbarian.com/unhandled-promise-rejections-in-node.js.html

Comment: I am sorry but this is a lot of unknown terms for me, can you answer me simply how I can get it solved?

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code:

`mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;`

Sets that the Mongoose library is returning promises to you now.
A promise is a data structure that helps you dealing with asynchronous code.

All queries to the Database are asynchronous which means they don't block the other code from running. Asynchronous code is executed via the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

When a promise returns a value you can pass in a callback if the promise is successfull via `.then` and pass a value in for failure via `.catch` For example:

```js
// create a new promise
let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
 if((Math.random() *10) >5){
   res();
 }else{
  rej();
  }
})

// call .then for success and .catch for failure
promise.then(()=>{
 console.log('im above 5');
}).catch(()=> {
 console.log('im below 5');
})

// this code gets executed first because its synchronous
console.log('im synchronous and get exectued before async');
```

To remove your specfic error you need to have error handling `.catch` methods on your promises which the mongoose library returns.

I recommend you reading more about asynchronous code [and promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and it will become clear to you after a while how it works ;)

Comment: Thanks, will definitely get into more depth about this. Trying to follow along with everything, but it's not the easiest start. Do you have any recommendations as to what kind of courses to follow? I usually learn better while watching/doing then reading.

Comment: Udemy has usually really good courses for good prices, just follow a course on Javascript and then Node.js

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into that. So what I don't understand is that I am actually currently following a course from Udemy about MongoDB and the instructor just puts in the line about global.promise etc and for him it all works out fine. I have just been following along with his code and everything's the same for both me and him, but for me the code doesn't work?

Comment: This is because his version of Node.js is older, there it was not considered an error when you did not handle the promises with an .catch clause